# Please help me for the correct My Code looping (C Language)

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
    int i;

    for(i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d Perulangan %d \n ", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me for the correct My Code looping (C Language) , i want print this output :

```txt
    1 perulangan 1
    2 perulangan 2
    3 perulangan 3
    4 perulangan 4
```

Comment: Does your compiler not give you any warnings about this code?

Comment: Your formatting string contains two format specifiers, but you've only put one variable in your `printf`.

Answer (score 4):

Super easy to do. Just add in an additional i parameter for the 2nd %d like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
    int i;

    for(i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d Perulangan %d \n ", i, i);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One would normally just repeat the argument.

```c
printf("%d Perulangan %d\n", i, i);
```

Alternatively, a POSIX-compliant compiler will accept references to arguments by position:

```c
printf("%1$d Perulangan %1$d\n", i);
```